Thermodynamics - Calculate enthalpy for reversible adiabatic process
So, this question came in IIT entrance exam in year 2000. The question is:
A sample of argon gas at $\pu{1 atm}$ pressure and $\pu{27 ^\circ C}$ expands reversible and adiabatically from $\pu{1.25 dm3}$ to $\pu{2.5 dm3}$. Calculate the enthalpy change in the process. $C_{v,m}$ for argon is $\pu{12.48 J K-1 mol-1}$.
I tried to use the relation
$$ \Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta PV $$
By the first law of thermodynamics,
$$ \Delta U = q + w$$
q is zero, since the process is adiabatic. And by using the work for reversible process $$ w = -\int^{v_2}_{v_1} Pdv $$
We get, $$ \Delta H =  \Delta PV  -\int^{v_2}_{v_1} Pdv $$.
Now I am stuck, since I don't know the final pressure I can't calculate $\Delta PV$. I know that for reversible adiabatic processes and for monoatomic gases like Argon, $\gamma = 5/3 $ and that $pv^{\gamma}$ is constant. But how can I apply them here? I tried to see some solutions online but they were using very complex relations so I couldn't understand where did these relation come from . I would be grateful if with solution you also tell me how to initiate thought process in such kind of questions

You could first use what you know to calculate the state of the gas (p,V,T) before and after the transformation.
I also think it is a better idea to work with the derivative form of the equations (little d instead of big delta) until the very end.
I assume that Ar is considered an ideal gas, otherwise this does not have a solution with the data you have.

du=-pdV is the start.

and dU=n.C_v,m . dT // Leading to after substitution p= nRT/V and integration to R ln (V1/V2)=C_v,m ln (T2/T1)
